# Disjoint images of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Are there any $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that for every root of unity $\zeta$, and every $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, $f(a) \neq g(b)?$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you won't be satisfied with the answer $f=0$ and $g=1$.  :)

But the answer is yes even if you assume that $f$ and $g$ are nonconstant.  For example, consider $f(x)=2x^3$ and $g(x)=(x^3-2)^3$.  If $f(a)=g(b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, then one finds that $2$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to post "A silly observation is you can take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$. So presumably you want $f$ and $g$ non-constant," and then follow that with the observation that the OP is looking at points on curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{ab}}$, for which it shouldn't be hard to produce examples with no points (as you just did).

Comment: So doesn't it mean that the answer is *yes*?

Comment: And what if $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{sol}}$ is taken instead of $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{ab}}$?

Comment: @ACL: Oops, yes.  I'll fix this.

Comment: @Pablo: I don't know how to do it for $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{sol}}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{ab}}$.  The trick behind my example above was to choose $f$ and $g$ so that $f(x)=g(y)$ has no geometrically irreducible component over $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{ab}}$, but that idea doesn't seem to be implementable over $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{sol}}$.  Whether every geometrically irreducible curve over $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{sol}}$ has a rational point is an open question, as far as I know.

Comment: @BjornPoonen another way to see this is that you have used the fact that $(\mathbb{Q}^{\text{ab}})^{\times}$ is not divisible, which obviously does not generalize to the field of radicals. Also note that curves which arise in this manner (i.e $f(x) - g(y)$) are of very specific type (no?) so it well may be that for these curves the existence of a rational point can be proved. I am even ready to restrict my attention to $f,g$ of degree $5$. What do you think?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are of degree $5$, with leading coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $f(x)=g(y)$ and the line $\alpha^{1/5} x = \beta^{1/5} y$ intersect in either the whole line or in four points with multiplicity (the fifth being at infinity in the projective closure); in either case, one finds solutions in $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{sol}}$, by solving a quartic equation if necessary.